# Notational confusion in a basic type declaration exercise

Tags: haskell

I'm going through the new book *Haskell Programming from First Principles*. It seems decent, but I feel that there are some confusing holes in the explanations. I apologize if I'm missing something basic.

The last problem in chapter 5 is to fill in the ??? below so that things make sense:

```hs
munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> x -> w
munge = ???
```

The solution which was explained to me (after much head-scratching) goes:

```hs
g :: y -> (w, z)
g = undefined

f :: x -> y
f = undefined

munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> x -> w
munge g f v = fst (g (f v))
```

I'm getting hung up on this example in two ways.

First, it seems like the `munge` function ought to take a *function* as input which takes `x -> y`. But the way `munge` is defined, it seems like we supply an additional argument `v` to the function `f` first. But if `f :: x -> y`, then won't the expression `f v` be of type just `y` instead of `x -> y`?

Second, I'm struggling to understand why the `x` appears in the second-to-last position in the type declaration. At that point I feel like the logical next piece after the `(y -> (w,x))` step should just be `w`, since at that stage the function `g` is being applied to `fst` and `w` ought to be the type of what `fst` returns. I can feel that I'm close, but can't quite close the gap.

Clearly I'm not understanding the notation correctly. Can anyone set me straight?

**EDIT**: Ok, here is a clarifying question to the second part. Is it possible to revise the `munge` function so that it has the following type (i.e. original type with second-to-last `x` application omitted)? If so what would it look like?

```
munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> w
```

Comment: @Alec: good point. thanks! I've edited it to make it less confusing, but I don't think that fully resolves my confusion.

Comment: It looks like they meant the definition to be `munge f g v = fst (g (f v))`

Comment: @Lee: ah, ok. I'm starting to get it. So in essence the order of the arguments on the left hand side specifies the order of application of the arguments, correct? Which is why when the `v` appears after `g` in the function definition, the `x` type also appears after the `(y -> (w,x))` in the type declaration. Is this on the right track?

Comment: Yes, there are three parameters in the type declaration, and three parameters in the definition, so `f` has type `x -> y`, `g` is `y -> (w, z)` and `x` has type `x`. Then `f v` has type `y` and `g (f v)` has type `(w, z)`. `fst` has type `(w, z) -> w` so `fst (g (f v))` has type `w` as required.

Comment: @Lee: right. but just to be clear, what I'm saying is that the type signature would be incorrect if it were written `(x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> w`, because the application of `v` (of type `x`, which happens after `f` and `g` are composed), is omitted. is that correct?

Comment: The last edit makes it impossible; there's no argument of type `x` which the first argument can be applied to, which means there is no way to get a value of `y` which the second function can be applied to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is incorrect and ill-typed. `f` and `g` should be swapped:

```
munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> x -> w
munge g f v = fst (f (g v))
```

I'm not sure if that clears up your confusion.

**EDIT** In case it's interesting, here are more equivalent ways of writing this function and its type:

```
-- notice parens in type signature; `->` associates right
munge :: (x -> y) -> ((y -> (w, z)) -> (x -> w))
munge g f v = -- omitted

-- type signature omitted
munge boop _plort zOWY = fst (_plort (boop zOWY))

munge g f = fst . f . g

munge g = \f v -> fst . f . g $ v

-- don't do this please
munge = ((fst .) .) . (.)
```

**EDIT2** It might be helpful to play around with this in GHCi, asking the inferred type of different expressions:

```
Prelude> let munge g f v = fst (f (g v))
Prelude> :t munge
munge :: (t1 -> t) -> (t -> (a, b)) -> t1 -> a
Prelude> :t munge head
munge head :: (t -> (a, b)) -> [t] -> a
Prelude> :t munge head (\x-> (x, not x))
munge head (\x-> (x, not x)) :: [Bool] -> Bool
Prelude> :t munge ((+1) . fst . snd . head)
munge ((+1) . fst . snd . head)
  :: Num t => (t -> (a, b)) -> [(a1, (t, b1))] -> a
```

Comment: Wait. I agree that something is swapped but shouldn't it be `munge f g v = fst (g (f v))` instead?

Comment: @gogurt that is equivalent. Can you see why?

Comment: ahhhhh. wait a second. I get the right-association and I can vaguely sense that this has to do with alpha equivalence. but my mind is being blown by the fact that the type declarations for `f` and `g` above seem completely irrelevant?

Comment: @gogurt I'm having trouble seeing what you're seeing. The typechecker understands the type of `g`, in the first definition of `munge` I gave, to be `(x -> y)` because the type signature states that the first argument is of that type. It doesn't matter if we name the first argument `f`, `g`, or `ploRTTCxx7`

Comment: OK, I see. Sorry, I was getting confused because in my original question, the answer I typed out involved explicit type declarations for `f` and `g` *outside of/before* the type declaration for `munge`. I was referring to that in my comment above. I realize now is that those separate type declarations are irrelevant, because the type declaration for `munge` contains all that information already. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No need to appologize, I see what you mean now. You're exactly right that `f` and `g` in `munge f g ...` are said to *shadow* the `f` and `g` you declared elsewhere, i.e. they create new bindings that have nothing to do with bindings of the same name which are in scope. If you compile with `-Wall` or do `:set -Wall` in ghci you will get a warning for this and lots of other good things

Comment: ahhh ok. much thanks. last comment: do you have any thoughts on the edit I just made re: the second part of this question?

Comment: @gogurt: the type `munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> w` reads "a function taking (a function from some `x` to some `y`) and (a function from that `y` to a tuple of some `w` and `z`) which yields some type `w`". Can you figure out how to get a `w` from the two function inputs to `munge`. What if the type of `munge` was `(x -> y) -> (y -> (Int, z)) -> x -> Int` (is there a (perhaps silly) implementation for this latter type possible). Some advanced reading: https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/05/parametricity/

Answer (score 2):

The solution, confusingly, is using the same variables `f` and `g` for two different things: as global names for two functions, and as parameter names in defining `munge`. Making a change of variable should make it clearer:

```
g :: y -> (w, z)
g = undefined

f :: x -> y
f = undefined

munge :: (x -> y) -> (y -> (w, z)) -> x -> w
munge f1 f2 v = fst (f2 (f1 v)) -- fst . f2 . f1 $ v
```

Then you would call `munge` on `f` and `g` will thing like

```
munge f g someArgumentForF
```

Inside `munge`, `f` (called `f1`) is first applied to `someArgumentForF` (called `v`) to get a value that can be passed to `g` (called `f2`). This produces a tuple, and applying `fst` to the tuple returns the value of type `w` needed as the final result.

Comment: Thanks for this. But the part I don't get is: if `f` is first applied to `someArgumentForF`, then how come the first step of the reduction is `(x -> y) -> ((y -> (w, z)) -> x -> w)`? Shouldn't the `x` typed variable come earlier in the reduction then?

Comment: The three arguments to `munge` could be given in any order, but this order lets you partially apply `munge` to the two function arguments in order to return a function of type `x -> w`.